# Firestore Security Rules Ignored for Specific Path

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am attempting to set up Firestore security rules for the document path /rooms/{roomId}/comments/{commentsId}.

Here are the specific rules I've set:

```js
match /rooms/{roomId}/comments/{commentsId} {
     allow read;
     allow write: if !request.resource.data.content.matches(".*http.*");
     allow delete;
}
```

However, I also need to enable global read and write access, for which I have the following configuration:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /rooms/{roomId}/comments/{commentsId} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if !request.resource.data.content.matches(".*http.*");
        allow delete;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that the specific rule for /rooms/{roomId}/comments/{commentsId} appears to be ignored, and I am unsure why. Here's a snapshot of the database structure:
[image: Database]

I've been struggling to identify the problem. Could someone please explain why the specific rule is ignored, and how I can correct this situation?

Comment: I wonder if this has the option that IIS has where you can deny directory browsing, so you can't just navigate to a link to view it, the link must be presented to a user in order for it to allow navigation, thus ensuring they are logged in and the right person before allowing access to the file.  Granted you could also define some rules in IIS to do this, but there is a built in feature for directory browsing that maybe, one can hope, google considered.

Comment: I have Nuxt app and if you does not allow read permission it is not navigating.

Comment: Ahh good, glad they provided that legacy support, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple matches, an operation allowed when it is allowed by any of those rules. So they're OR'd together. From the documentation on [overlapping match statements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements):

> It's possible for a document to match more than one match statement. In the case where multiple `allow` expressions match a request, the access is allowed if **any** of the conditions is `true`

You could change the second rule to explicitly exclude `rooms`:

```
match /{collection}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if collection != 'rooms';
}
```

Comment: It was blocking read so I divided allow read and allow write and it works
match /{collection}/{document=**} {
      allow read;
     allow write: if collection != 'rooms';
    }
If it is correct way you can modify your answer and I'll accept it as correct answer :* 
Thanks a lot.